# pytorch copying weights only worked with colon

Tags: python, pytorch

```
    resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    reg_resnet = resnet_model()
    for each_param in resnet18.state_dict().keys():
        reg_resnet.state_dict()[each_param][:] = resnet18.state_dict()[each_param]
```

The above code worked for me in updating the weights of my reg_resnet model (which is initialized from scratch) with pretrained weights of resnet 18. But it ddidn't work when I had the below:

```
resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
reg_resnet = resnet_model()
for each_param in resnet18.state_dict().keys():
    reg_resnet.state_dict()[each_param] = resnet18.state_dict()[each_param]
```

Why is it that adding the '[:]' made it work? What does that do in pytorch?

Comment: What exactly does "But it ddidn't work" mean? Show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. I just meant that the model didn't seem to get all the weights properly since the training loss was much worse

Comment: Please be [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try e.g. to manually examine whether the weights got carried over. And [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60597356/edit) the additional information into the question.

Comment: The code seems good, the difference probably came from somewhere else

Comment: it looks like "referencing" vs "copy values" difference.